# Is there any Event for select text from mail body?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I try to catch selection text change event on mail body.
Idea to get the text when selection changed and show in textbox.

I got a document object but is there any event for selection change ?

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
Outlook.Inspector inspector = mailItem.GetInspector;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something similar to this.

[Text Selection Change Event in Outlook Inspector Window](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c77e6350-0b5a-48d7-aa20-01a7d418062c/text-selection-change-event-in-outlook-inspector-window?forum=vsto)

You'll want to get the `Application` from the `Document` and attach to the `WindowSelectionChanged` event.

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
Outlook.Inspector inspector = mailItem.GetInspector;
Word.Document document = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;
Word.Application app = document.Application;
app.WindowSelectionChange += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler(YOUR_METHOD_HERE);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the even fires only when the selection changes. It does **not** fire as the user types (you'd think that selection changes, but the event does not fire).

Comment: thank you for reply but it seems that event doesn't exist i add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word v15 http://prntscr.com/bbg37l

Comment: app.WindowSelectionChange instead of app.WindowSelectionChanged and t working for me

Comment: @mokhAkh Whoops. My bad, I couldn't test it before sending. Glad it works.